# How to tell if there is fault in the truth table?

Tags: cpu-architecture, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, truthtable, boolean-algebra

In my digital design and computer architecture class.Our teacher gave a truth table for which we had to construct a K-map and minimize it to find the boolean expression

But some of the students quickly identified that there were mistakes in the truth table and started pointing out the mistake.How did they do that?Is there a way to identify mistakes in a truth table?What am I missing?

[image: 4 input truth table]

Comment: Does this also have a clock signal.

Comment: For which gate is this truth table for?

Comment: If they are using k-map réduction this isn’t a single gate.  It looks like a state machine truth table but that only make sense if you have a starting state and/or a clock.  Otherwise there are many issue As some input combinations have multiple declared outputs.

Comment: @AagamSheth,this isn't  for a single gate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this truth table, there are four inputs.

That would mean you would have every combination of settings across inputs (a, b, c, and d).  However, this table has two entries for (0, 0, 0, 0) and no entry for (0, 0, 0, 1)

Since the table doesn't cover all the inputs, there is an error in the table because it does not detail what Y should be for (0, 0, 0, 1)  In addition, there are two answers for (0, 0, 0, 0), answer (0) and answer (1).  Since any logical mapping of inputs can only lead to one output, this table has a second different kind of error.

Comment: Just because a combination isn’t declared doesn’t mean that combination is invalid.  Instead it is indeterminate as is in doesn’t matter (Sometimes shown with an X for the output.)

Comment: Okay I get it.Thanks a ton.Also I think the one that is repeating here is (0,0,1,0) with outputs 1 and 0 right?

Comment: @SavannahMadison: Yes, there are several conflicts.  Possibly the `d` and `y` columns were accidentally switched by whoever made the table.  (And several states where the table doesn't define an output, but as Matthew points out that's not necessarily an error; don't-care output for some inputs gives you freedom to implement it with different combinations of simpler gates.  But given that the table has as many rows as possible input states, that's almost certainly not intended in this case.)

Comment: A "don't care" output is not the same as two clear outputs for one input, Typically one uses a different notation for "don't care" like a "-" or a "x".  But, even if you think the duplicate outputs combine to a don't care output, then why have the additional missing inputs unless they also represent a don't care output, and then why have two ways of showing a don't care output?  In this case I don't think it represents a don't care output, as the entire table reduces to "don't care" outputs for all specified inputs.

Comment: Agreed; usually you'd show every possible input state, with don't-care explicitly shown, not just implied from a missing row.  I definitely wasn't arguing that conflicting outputs represented a don't-care.  I was saying that's a 100% clear sign the table is faulty, unlike leaving some states unlisted (which could plausibly be intentional if the table was only half as long).

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the clarifications.  I agree with you fully.  This looks like a bad problem, because it is asked incorrectly.  We can work it into a "workable" problem; but, we will never know if our choices match what the intent of the request was because the request itself is nearly nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

The thing with truth table in the question is, it contains two similar inputs (0,0,0,0) and (1,1,1,1) with two different answers (0) and (1) in both, with this I mean (0,0,0,0) has two outputs (1) and (0) and it's same with (1,1,1,1).And,logically,there can't be 2 different outputs of a mapping with similar inputs.

Comment: Your table has an output of "0" for input (0, 0, 0, 0) This is clearly wrong, because the table in the question has an output of "1" for input (0,0,0,0).  If you update your answer to have an output of "1" for input (0, 0, 0, 0) then your answer is clearly wrong again because the table in the question has an answer of "0" for input (0, 0, 0, 0).  It's not a matter of knowing how to solve a boolean logic problem, it's a matter of this problem doesn't provide a clear request.  Every specified input has answers of 0 AND 1.  And many of the inputs are not specified at all.

Comment: The question doesn't specify what "y" is? So I tried to help @Savannah_Madison the thing by an example of equation. Thank you for pointing out the mistake. Thing was about not mentioned gates and 2 different outputs for the single input(which is incorrect logically). I thought it in a different way. My previous answer was focusing on the easy ways for table forming.I hope the edited answer is correct.